# \foreach dimension too big

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I want to create an animation of satellites. I am using the code below. However I'd like it to run smoothly so I want to produce many frames. It turns out the maximum number of frames I can create via `\foreach` is 45. If I change to 46 I get the error `Dimension too large`.

So, how can I do 45+ `\foreach` loops?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.5]
  \setbeamercovered{invisible}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Jradius}{0.3}   % Jupiter radius
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\IoOrbit}{1}   % Io radius
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Iradius}{0.1} % Earth radius


  \fill[red] (0,0) circle (\Jradius);

  \draw[thin] (0,0) circle (\IoOrbit);

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{45} %If 46 or more, then error.
  \foreach \k in {0,1,...,\N}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{360*\k/\N}
      \pgfmathparse{int(\k+1)}
      \onslide<\pgfmathresult>{
        \fill[gray] ({cos(\theta)},{sin(\theta)}) circle (\Iradius);
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not the `\foreach` it is the ` \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{360*\k/\N}` that causes the problem. No idea why

Comment: Of course: 360*46 is too large for it to handle, but `(360/N)*\k` is not

Comment: Reverse the order `{360/\N*\k}`

Comment: Didn't imagine the order would be important, I guess it does because 360*46 is bigger than the allowed number latex handles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the calculation of `\pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{360*\k/\N}` `360*\k` easily becomes bigger than what LaTeX can handle. Reversing the multiplication order, solves this:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{360/\N*\k}
```